# Call WCF from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf

I have asp page that need to access a client resource. Can I put the client code in a Windows Service and install it on client machine and call that service in asp JavaScript page?

Thanks

Comment: let me say that i have code i need it to be excuted in client side

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if it's possible to call a WCF service using Javascript?  Obviously the answer is yes, any book on WCF will show you how.